How to extract local device density of states (LDDOS) after Transiesta calculations?

The simulated band diagram and local device density of states (LDDOS) of
the monolayer MoS2 with double-end Sb (0112) electrodes: without electron
doping (zero gate bias) (a) and with 1.5 electron doping (similar to high gate
bias)[1]

[1] Li, W., Gong, X., Yu, Z. et al. Approaching the quantum limit in two-dimensional semiconductor contacts. Nature 613, 274–279 (2023). https://doi.org/10.1038/s41586-022-05431-4

I am using TranSiesta to reproduce the above results in this article [1]. What routine should I use to process which output file of Transiesta?
Any suggestions will be appreciated!
